# Blender resets restricted rendering settings upon frame change

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using CellBlender for particle simulations and now want to extract a series of pictures using the render feature. The issue now is that my simulations contain many different particle species, but there are only a few that are interesting for illustrating purposes. Once I turned them all of for rendering, render a picture, and go to the next frame I have to turn them off again, because these settings are not being saved. 
How can I prevent them from being reset, s.t. I can browse between frames without having to change the settings again?

Also, is there some form of batch rendering? Instead of rendering an animation, I just need every frame by itself.

[image: frame 0 with manually turned or species for rendering]
[image: switched to frame 2, the species turned themselves on again]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to come up with a workaround for both my questions.
It is possible to remove desired particle species for all frames of the render by setting their radius ('scale factor') to 0 in the 'Molecule' section of the Cellblender add-on. They will therefore still be turned on for the render, but invisible due to zero volume.

This enables to not just render one or multiple images, but also an whole animation. Then it is possible to extract all single frames of that animation either from the temporary directory by hand or by choosing 'save all images' of the render window.